# setAutoresizingMask not working for UIView added to self.window

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

I added a UIView object to the main window. Is it possible to make "setAutoresizingMask" work for that?.

My code is

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self.sampleView];
```

I wanted to show that view over the videoPlayer playing from the app. That is why I had to add it like that.